# asp.net change gridview cell if two table columns got the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, right-join, datagridviewcellstyle

so i got this little issue with my gridview in asp.net and mysql:
I have two tables with several columns. In both tables i have a Column ("Name").

I wanted to Show the whole Table 1 in my gridview and mark the rows that match the values in the second table in red or some other Colors.

I used the Right Join and can Display the matching result... but not the other records in table1 i wanted to Show (not matching records = Color green).

Can anyone help me with this Problem? or give a hint to a solution?

Comment: please add you code here in detail. so we edit in you code for your help. its very time consuming to write whole bunch of code.

Comment: i dont want the Code ^^ but thanks.. Right now my SQL query is like this: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 FULL JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Name = TABLE2.Name`   I get the result.. but the matching result between Table1.Name and Table2,Name  i want the row or a specific Cell to be in a different color in in my Gridview.

Answer (score -1):

You can used the `inner join` instead of `right join` to get only matching records

```
SELECT tbl1.Color FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.Name=tbl2.Name;
```